# Having issues with nested loops

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

When running the moveRight() function I am getting an error with it not recognizing map[x][y], saying that is is undefined. This only happens when "Player" is in the last y loop. I don't understand why this is happening, could somebody help explain?

```
var map = [
    ["Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"],
    ["Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"],
    ["Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"],
    ["Blank", "Player", "Blank", "Blank"],
    ["Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"],
    ["Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"],
    ["Blank", "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"]
];

function moveRight() {
    var breakLoop = false;
    for (y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {

            var posX = map[x][y].indexOf("Player");
            if (posX <= -1) continue;
            if (y >= map[y].length-1) {
                breakLoop = true;
                break;
            }

            breakLoop = true;
            console.log("x: " + x);
            console.log("y: " + y);

            map[x][y] = "Blank";
            map[x][y+1] = "Player"; 
            break;
        }
        if (breakLoop) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to declare a variable (like `y` or `x`), you should put a `var` in front of it. Your `y` and `x` are leaking into global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written your loops with `y` in the outer loop and `x` in the inner one, the map needs to be accessed by `y` first, then `x`.

```
var posX = map[y].indexOf("Player");
```

Then the `y` bounds check should instead check `x`, which makes sense since this is a horizontal movement.

```
if (x >= map[y].length - 1) {
```

The movement lines should be:

```
map[y][x] = "Blank";
map[y][x+1] = "Player";
```

Additionally, it's a good idea to add `var` to your local variable declarations so they don't leak into the global scope.

```
for (var y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < map[y].length; x++) {
```

Finally, it doesn't look like you need the inner loop. You're searching through each row with `indexOf` so there's no need to iterate over each individual square in the rows. Which means `posX` can become `x`.

---

Applying all of these ideas, here's the final code. Notice how some careful refactoring lets us get rid of the `breakLoop` variable as well.

```
for (var y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
    var x = map[y].indexOf("Player");

    if (x <= -1) {
        continue;
    }

    if (x < map[y].length - 1) {
        console.log("x: " + x);
        console.log("y: " + y);

        map[y][x]     = "Blank";
        map[y][x + 1] = "Player"; 
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was vary helpful. One thing I don't understand though is how the x variable still works in the last version you made. When var x = map[x][y], how does map[x] know what value to be if there is no var x loop??

Comment: @AlphaCentauriAB Oops, that was a typo. Fixed that line.

Answer (score 1):

The loops are structured to have `y` be the first index and `x` be the second.  In the following 2 lines though you are using them in the wrong order

```
map[x][y] = "Blank";
map[x][y+1] = "Player";
```

It should be

```
map[y][x] = "Blank";
map[y + 1][x] = "Player";
```

Additionally the `y + 1` index is suspicious.  On the last iteration of the loop it will be outside the bounds of the array.  Did you mean to change the loop conditional to be `y + 1 < map.length`?